# Apache X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN is always appended

Tags: django, apache, x-frame-options

I'm running the same django project on two Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS webservers (one "real" and one VM).
Because this project has to run in an iframe at another website, I had to change to X-Frame-Options.

At my VM I only had to change the security.conf and insert 
`Header set X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW-FROM https://example.org"`
This is the part in the HTML header: 
`X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://example.org`

At the real server I tried to have the same configuration. But the HTML header looks that way: `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN ALLOW-FROM https://example.org`

And I don't have any idea, where this SAMEORIGIN is set.
Do you know, where I have to look for this option? If looked through all confs in the directory (and subdirectories)/etc/apache2, but found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django, it's possible that you have the [Clickjacking middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/clickjacking/#preventing-clickjacking) installed. Look for this in your settings.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

This would be sent back from your app server to Apache, and Apache would send it to the browser as a pass-through HTTP header.