# Django - get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'header'

Tags: python, django, rest, urllib

I am trying to develop a REST-ful API where IoT devices upload data to the server. I am using a python program to simulate that using `urllib` during development.

Sometimes the program uploads successfully, but other times returns a `HTTP 500` with the following Django error information.

```
TypeError at /logdata/
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'header'
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 2.0.3
...
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.5.3
```

I found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45906625/5850658) dealing with HTML forms, but I am doing simply raw POST requests with URL-encoded data, and hence do not need a HttpResponseRedirect do I? I only return `HttpResponseBadRequest` when invalid data is sent, and `application/json` data when the request is valid.

Here is a simplified version of my Django view:

```
def publish_data(request):
    params = request.POST
    if validate(params):
        ...    # do stuff with params
        return HTTPResponse(my_data, content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid Data')
```

The exception location seems to be tied to setting `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` which I tried to do manually within my Django view, but I still get the HTTP 500 error. Any ideas for common pitfalls I can check for?

Comment: Mind posting the entire snippet—data being sent, etc? The data you're trying to pass might be invalid. There's also a small chance Adware or Click Jacking modules have been installed without your knowledge. More info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36205263/9896970)

Comment: Right now I am just doing testing within Docker, and then sending the data through my python interpreter, so I don't think that click jacking modules have been installed.